# Get step function values from matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I have 2 numpy arrays with data, say `x,y`, and I apply `plt.step()` and get a continues (step) curve of it.

I would like to be able to create this function by my own, meaning I want to have an (zero order hold) step approximation to the value of `y` for `x` that does not actually exist in the original `x` array.

For example, in the following link I want to have the 'new' actual rectangle sine values, and not only plotted:
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/step_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-step-demo-py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scipy's [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) to create a step function. Default the interpolation is 'linear', but you can change it to 'next', 'previous' or 'nearest' for a step function.

A standard step function is obtained from `step_fun = interp1d(x, y, kind='previous')` and then calling it as `step_fun(new_x)`.

The following code compares different types of "interpolation":

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.7, 20).cumsum()
y = np.sin(x)

kinds = ['linear', 'previous', 'next', 'nearest', 'cubic']
for i, kind in enumerate(kinds):
    function_from_points = interp1d(x, y + i, kind=kind)
    x_detailed = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 1000)
    plt.plot(x_detailed, function_from_points(x_detailed), color='dodgerblue')
    plt.scatter(x, y + i, color='crimson')
plt.yticks(range(len(kinds)), kinds)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 0):

You can choose tick values and corresponding function values whichever you want. This is an example not equally spaced arguments and their values:

```
x = np.arange(20) + np.random.random(20)/2
y = np.sin(x / 2)**2 + np.random.random(20)/5
```

**Remark: these two arrays must have equal size.** If you want your own custom function, you can use `np.vectorise`:

```
x = np.arange(20) + np.random.random(20)/2
func = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.sin(x) + np.random.random()/5)
y = func(x)
```